# Program stopped working and giving garbage value C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm making a program for Dynamic Array, Where I implemented three methods. push_back(arguments...),pop_back(arguments...) and printArray(arguments...).

But when I increase the size of the array it gives the garbage value at that index and if I run the code for more than 15 values it stop working.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void push_back(unsigned int value,unsigned int *array,int &arraySize,int &totalArrayItems ){
  if(arraySize>totalArrayItems){
    array[totalArrayItems]=value;
    totalArrayItems=totalArrayItems+1;
    cout<<"Current size: "<<arraySize<<endl;
  }
  else if(arraySize==totalArrayItems){
      cout<<"Adding the Size of Array... \n";

    unsigned int *tempArray=new unsigned int[arraySize+5];//making new array as asked in requirements
    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){

      tempArray[i]=array[i];
      cout<<"Value in Temp : "<<tempArray[i]<<endl;
    }
    unsigned int *temp=array;
    array=tempArray;
    arraySize=arraySize+5;
    cout<<"Saving "<<value<<" at Position: "<<totalArrayItems<<endl;
    array[totalArrayItems]=value;//adding the new value
    cout<<"Value in Temp "<<totalArrayItems<<" : "<<tempArray[totalArrayItems]<<endl;
    totalArrayItems=totalArrayItems+1;
    cout<<"Updated size: "<<arraySize<<"Current value: "<<value<<endl;
    delete []temp;//delete old array

  }


}
void pop_back(unsigned int *array,int &arraySize,int &totalArrayItems){
  if(totalArrayItems>0){
    totalArrayItems=totalArrayItems-1;
    if(totalArrayItems<(arraySize-5)){
        unsigned int *tempArray=new unsigned int[arraySize-5];
        for(int i=0;i <= totalArrayItems;i++){
          tempArray[i]=array[i];
        }
        unsigned int *temp=array;
        array=tempArray;
        delete[] temp;
        arraySize=arraySize-5;
    }
  }
}
  void printArray(unsigned int *array,int totalArrayItems){
    for(int i=0;i<totalArrayItems;i++){
      cout<<"Value at "<<i<<" : "<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you make your program into a [mcve] and clearly state what the expected output is - and what it becomes instead?

Comment: Sorry for the whole code.
The issue is where I dynamically allocate the memory and assign that memory back to same pointer. It doesn't store value at that index and print garbage value. If I run this program for more than 15 values, it stopped working.

Comment: I'm sure that's your current analysis, but if you remove bit for bit from the program, eventually you will find the true cause, or you need to narraow it down even better.

Comment: I never passed a pointer by reference before, because I think pointer name itself is a reference but here I should pass it by reference. I didn't know it before, thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind. :)

Comment: There are plenty of `function(type*&)` overloads in the standard library. They are quite useful.

Comment: It's new learning for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unsigned int* array` in `push_back` is a local variable. When you assign a new value to it (a new pointer to a new memory location), it doesn't update the value of `array` in whatever method you called it from.

Pass a pointer to `int*` instead: `int**`, if you want your reallocations to stick.

Comment: Thank You so much!
It worked, I am now accepting the reference of the pointer and it worked.